# What does decrypt the key mean? in parity wallet transfere

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I just created a Wallet in Parity 1.8.0 and transfered there some ether from main account using a passphrase in Parity signer. Now as I'm trying to send a sum from the Wallet to yet another account, the Parity signer asks to "decrypt the key"/ who knows what that could be? I was never asked to create any key, nor encrypt it. Seems locked in my wallet & I am not able to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's the password you created to protect your account. If you didn't create any, leave it blank.